# Partialview and passing data to layout MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

i want to show categories to all pages by using layout and here my way:
here my model (NewsCategoriesModel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;


namespace GiaoXuKeSat.Models
{
    public class NewsCategoriesModel
    {
        public int NewsCategoriesID { get; set; }
        public string NewsCategoriesName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here Partialview (_NewsCategories)

```
@using System.Linq;


@using System.Linq;
@model IEnumerable<GiaoXuKeSat.Models.dms_NewsCategory>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <ul id="dmsMenuULUL">
     <li>@item.NewsCategoriesName</li>
</ul>     
}
```

and i print that partialview to layout

```
@Html.Partial("_NewsCategories");
```

but i got Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the model that your partial view needs to it.  Such as.

```
@Html.Partial("_NewsCategories", Model.NewsItems);
```

If you leave the model out, you are simply passing the current view model to your partial.  You can also use the ViewBag.

If you are calling a Partial from the master/layout page it is unlikely you'll have your model available on every single page.  So in this case, it is better to create a controller/action that returns your news item model to a partial view and then call with...

```
@Html.Action("NewsCategories", "NewsController");
```

Which will then run the specified action and display the partial view that the action calls.

Comment: i want to passing data to layout, how can i set viewbag? the Datas get from database using linq to sql?

Comment: Here is a blog post that should provide you with some information that you are looking for.  http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

Comment: Also, if you are trying to add a partial to your master page (aka the layout page).  You might want to consider using @Html.Action, which will allow you to call a Controller/Action, which will then function like any other action, but you pass the result to a partial view.  Works great for master/layout pages.

Comment: I believe you mean @Html.Partial("_NewCategories") instead? A copy of the current model is automatically sent to the partial.

Comment: Ah, quite right, but if the model for his Partial view is different from the current model, he'll have to pass the correct model.  But I guess saying Model is a bit misleading.  Will correct post.